# Images in a slick carousel don't appear first time, but do the second

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been butting my head against this problem for months, and cannot figure out what might be causing it.

I'm using the Slick JS carousel in a Bootstrap site. When you first load the page the images don't appear, but will if you go to a second page with the carousel on (or press enter in the address bar) but not if you hit the refresh button (i.e., ask the browser to get the images again).

Not really possible to build it as a jsfiddle as it's so integrated into the test site (and it probably wouldn't recreate the problem), but you can see the prototype here: http://webeditors.co.uk/se/course.php

Some symptoms of the problem are that other images on the page are unaffected - it's only the images in the carousel. Inspecting the page shows that the browser thinks the images should be there, and they appear in the resources for the page.

Any suggestions of what I should be looking for? I've tried preloading images via JS; changing the visibility settings; using window load rather than document ready. My next options will probably involve waving voodoo dolls over the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this turned out to be a third-party conflict. I was using Capty to add captions to each of the slide items and for whatever reason, Capty was causing this. My solution was to remove Capty and just use the Bootstrap tooltips for labels.